# R: Finding standard deviation of each element across three dataframes

Tags: r

I have three dataframes and I would like to find the standard deviation of each element across the dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4,c=3:5)
df1

df2 <- data.frame(a=4:6,b=5:7,c=6:8)
df2

df3 <- data.frame(a=7:9,b=8:10,c=9:11)
df3
```

I tried:

```
sd(c(df1,df2,df3))
```

but this gave an error.
I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: `sapply(rbind(df1, df2, df3), sd)`

Comment: yes, nine altogether ie  (row1,col1;  row2,col2, row3,col3, row1,col2 ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the standard deviation once for a, b, and c (combining the three data frames together), you can follow @d.b's comments:

```
sapply(rbind(df1, df2, df3), sd)
```

Where you first combine all three into one data frame and compute the standard deviation via sapply.

If you want to do them three times for each data frame individually, you could do this:

```
listofdfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)
for(i in listofdfs){
print(sapply(i, sd))}
```

Or suggested by @d.b

```
sapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), function(x) sapply(x, sd))
```

Comment: `sapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), function(x) sapply(x, sd))`

Answer (score 1):

An easier option is to create an `array` after `unlist`ing the datasets, specify the `MARGIN` and apply the `sd` for elementwise `sd`

```
apply(array(unlist(mget(paste0('df', 1:3))), c(3, 3, 3)), 1:2, sd)
```

---

Or withh `rowSds` with `MARGIN` as 1

```
library(matrixStats)
apply(array(unlist(mget(paste0('df', 1:3))), c(3, 3, 3)), 1, rowSds)
```

---

Or another option would be to create a single dataset and then grouped by row number, get the `sd` of each column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mget(paste0("df", 1:3)) %>%
    map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                  mutate(rn = row_number())) %>%
      group_by(rn) %>% 
      summarise_all(sd)
```